# Second Graph is not showing up chart.js, mysql in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

I can't figure out why my second graph isn't showing on web? I am using chart.js and querying data from mysql, and graphing it. I have two functions drawChat1 and drawChart2. drawChart1 is working fine and showing graph but no data is showing for drawChart2. I left a picture for reference.

**UPDATE**: it is the id's. I tried rearrange the order in which I call them, and now graph2 is showing whereas graph1 isn't. But how do I fix this? I have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are usign vars so high chance its a name conflict, if you switch the naming of your `draw2` method to `data2`, `options2` and `chart2` it will work.

Comment: function drawChart2() {

        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Cause', 'Frequency'],
          <?php

          while($chart = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
          {       
              echo "['".$chart['cause']."',".$chart['id']."],";
          }
          ?>  
        ]);
      var options2 = {
          title: 'Cause'
        };
        var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_divtwo'));
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);
      }

Comment: OMG! It is the id's. I tried rearrange the order in which I call them, and now graph2 is showing whereas graph1 isn't. But how do i fix this? I have no clue

Comment: ok so I couldn't fix the problem but I found a solution. when I hide one chart, the other shows, so I will create a button to hide/show each graph